# Парсинг таблицы по значением с обработкой

Tags: php

Имеется база вида:

```
id | user_from | user_to | amount
0   admin       relot      1000
1   topo        admin      30
```

и тд.
Нужно сделать так, например мы вводим имя admin, код просматривает все строки и если admin встречается в user-form то значение amount он вычитает, если admin встречается в user_to то значение amount прибавляется, код должен проходить по всей таблице, и окончательный результат записывать в одну переменную, как это организовать?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под словом "база" и "таблица" ? У вас что ли файл на диске с таким содержимым ? А то когда говорят "база", мне кажется, что это некая SQL база и следовательно получение и изменение конкретной строки описывается одним sql запросом

Comment: да сама таблица в базе данных mysql 
SELECT amount FROM dbName WHERE user_from="admin"
Так мы получим все amount в строка которого user_from = admin , но как теперь все строки amount сложить?

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(if(user_from='admin',-1,1) * amount)
  from dbName
 where 'admin' in(user_from,user_to)
```

Групповая функция `sum` суммирует по всем строкам (или по группе, при наличии `group by`) значения. `if` в данном случае делает отрицательной сумму, если искомый admin в user_from